# Using the Dynamic Device Tree to add Overlays at Run Time

Tags: pi-4, boot, pi-3b+, device-tree

I am working on a couple of ideas for *device tree overlays* for the RPi 3B+ & 4B. It will be useful in my testing to be able to load and unload overlays without having to reboot each time. As described in [The Dynamic Device Tree](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#part3.5), the `dtoverlay` command is able to accomplish this loading and un-loading at run time - a useful feature I think. Additional usage documentation is contained in `man dtoverlay`.

The documentation contains several important caveats wrt use of the `dtoverlay` command. I think I've respected these caveats, but `dtoverlay` doesn't seem to be working exactly as described in this official documentation; specifically wrt ***listing*** overlays that are in use/*loaded*.

##### Specifically:

`dtoverlay -a` and `dtoverlay -l` are similar. The former lists all *defined* overlays and places an asterisk (*) next to the ones that are loaded; the latter lists all currently loaded overlays.

Running `dtoverlay -a` lists all overlays, but *none are shown as loaded* (i.e. no `*` for any item in the list). Running `dtoverlay -l` lists nothing at all.

I know that there are several overlays loaded because: **a)** they are included in `/boot/config.txt`, and **b)** I can verify they are operating.

I've found that if I **defer** loading an overlay, both of these commands seem to work as advertised; i.e. I remove the dtoverlay from `/boot/config.txt`, reboot, load the overlay *dynamically* with `sudo dtoverlay gpio-led gpio=25`, then it ***does*** show up in the listings as loaded.

And so this is my question: It seems odd that `dtoverlay` distinguishes an overlay *loaded* at boot time from one that is *loaded* at run time. *How does `dtoverlay` know the difference, and why does it care?*

---

This question is similar to an [older question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/62903/how-to-detect-a-device-tree-overlay-at-run-time), but that Q&A did not cover usage of the *new-ish* `dtoverlay` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question 6 months ago, and as I've gotten no answer I'll **assume** that the answer is that the `dtoverlay` command is incapable of accessing *overlays* that were loaded at boot time; i.e. the `dtoverlay` command deals only with *overlays* that are/were loaded at run time.

The documentation is ambiguous IMHO, but the following may be a clue:

> an overlay or parameter applied by the firmware becomes "baked in" such that it won’t be listed by dtoverlay and can’t be removed.

Again, this strikes me as ambiguous, but if one interprets this statement to mean that the *dynamic device tree* is an ***ephemeral device tree*** which is separate and apart from the device tree created at boot time, then perhaps it makes a bit more sense. In other words, `dtoverlay` is completely ignorant of the boot time device tree. I guess the thinking was that *limited* runtime utility is better than none at all.

I am marking this as the *"Accepted"* answer for now, but will gladly change that if a definitive answer is supplied.

Comment: I often use dtoverlay & dtparam at run time for testing and can confirm that those loaded at boot are invisible at run time. Initially I expected that I could at least list them if not delete.

Comment: @Milliways: That's good to know - thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @Seamus so I assume right way is to remove dtoverlay line from config.txt to be able to switch overlays without reboots? Do they work as intended when loading and unloading with dtoverlay command on demand?

Comment: @laimison: If I understand your question, the answer is "yes"... don't place overlays in `config.txt` that you intend to add & remove dynamically.