# Rasperry Pi 4 - Python i2c Device Not Found

Tags: python, i2c

I'm having a hard time setting up a i2c device on a pi4.
[image]

I did `i2cdetect -y 1`

[image]

But when I run the python code

```
import board
import busio

import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1115 as ADS

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn

ads = ADS.ADS1115(i2c)

chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)

print(chan.value, chan.voltage)
```

I get `ValueError: No I2C device at address: 0x48`

and printing out the value for board.SCL and board.SDA its 3 and 2 respectively.
Am I calling the i2c incorrectly?

Comment: Could you print the values of board.SCL and  board.SDA and add it to your question.

Comment: @joan yea, its board.SCL is 3, and board.SDA is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Python for these things, but on my side of the tracks I have to make an entry in `/boot/config.txt` to enable the appropriate *device tree overlay* before the driver is able to connect to the device.

Assuming your device is the ADS1115, you can add the following entry to `/boot/config.txt` & reboot. Running `i2cdetect -y 1` should show the symbol `UU` at address 48, indicating the driver has connected.

```
dtoverlay=ads1115 <options as required>
# Read  the file '/boot/overlays/README' to see the additional options that my need to be configured.
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`dtoverlay` command to invoke the *dynamic device tree*](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#part3.5). AIUI, this is not a *permanent* change, but may be useful for testing when it's not convenient to `reboot`. Also FWIW, [last I tried the dynamic device tree](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/136839/83790), it seemed a rough and unfinished project - it may or may not have improved since.

Comment: ty, this did the trick!